# What is the collective term for "Daily", "Weekly", "Monthly" and "Yearly"?

Tags: word-choice, recurring-events

I am developing a business application in which the user can select from one of these options, namely "Daily", "Weekly", "Monthly" or "Yearly", for scheduling appointments. I need to create a field in the database to hold this value, but am at a loss for what to name the field.

What would be the collective term? In Outlook, the combination of the option plus the option-specific sub-options is headed "Recurrence pattern", but that obviously applies to the complete selection. I am only interested in the collective term for "Daily", "Weekly", "Monthly" and "Yearly".

Perhaps just "recurrence"?

Comment: yes, *recurrence*

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because choosing names for things in programming is explicitly off-charter for ELU.

Comment: @tchrist, I could of course remove any mention of the fact that I am busy developing a software system; will that make the question acceptable?

Comment: @tchrist: it's not *"choosing a name for a thing"*. It's a legit enquiry about the correct English term to use, which is on-topic. Just as legit as enquiries about the correct English term to use in gardening, heraldry or anything else.

Comment: @smci Do you also feel that is somehow *not* a duplicate of either of the two questions under the "LINKED" column at the right of this page? Or should it be closed as a duplicate of one or both of those two?

Comment: I'm an English speaker and a programmer, and I'm legitimately curious about what this would be called as well. Just like finding out that the "st" after `1st` or "nd" after `2nd` is called the **ordinal**. Keep the question open!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

***[Periodicity](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/periodicity):***

> - The quality or state of being periodic; recurrence at regular intervals.

(AHD)

Comment: Sorry, it took me two years, but I finally accepted this answer as it seems to address most use cases for this requirement.

Answer (score 12):

You could always use headings like ***Time*** or ***Frequency*** in your application. I would say ***frequency*** sounds better than ***recurrence*** here.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @Vitamin C that ***frequency*** is better, but recognize that another category is needed in your list of options, too, such as "as needed" or "irregular."