# What's the generic word for weekly/monthly etc. service?

Tags: word-choice

My guesses are: recurring or cyclic order/service.

In what cases would you use one or the other?

**Context**:
A customer can book a one-time service or choose an interval. I'd like to name a service that is not one-time but repeats every week/month etc.

Comment: I strongly agree with 'recurring service.' Please write it as an answer, @Max Williams, because answers posted as comments may get deleted.

Comment: It's not worth an answer, especially when you already said it in your question.

Comment: Depending on what the service is, sometimes "subscription" is appropriate. For example : *"As a platinum service subscriber you will be entitled to monthly product updates and 24/7 telephone support"*

Comment: Why not look at a calendar app on your phone or computer or online and see what term it uses?

Comment: So far none of the answers tackle your question about when you would use one or the other - so I'm going to suggest 'recurring' for services, appointments etc ie _events_, whereas 'cyclic', IMO suggests something that moves through two or more different _states_; for instance the lunar cycle, 4-stroke cycle, cycle of the seasons. . .

Comment: Related (I don't think it's a duplicate): https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/326819/what-is-the-collective-term-for-daily-weekly-monthly-and-yearly

Answer (score 94, accepted):

There are several possible words that could be used here:

1. ***regular***, as @Lawrence suggests
2. ***periodic***
   ([Oxford](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/periodic), definition 1, "Appearing or occurring at intervals.")
3. ***recurring*** or ***recurrent***, which you used in your question.
4. ***repeating*** is a perfectly valid word for this use.

Comment: This should really be the accepted answer; regular is ok but somewhat ambiguous, because there is even a connotation of "Oh I see him regularly" that only means frequently, not periodically.

Comment: Periodic is what I would use when trying to focus on the interval.

Comment: I'm not a native English speaker, but in mathematics, *periodic* is the word used for this kind of regularity, something repeating with a constant interval. Isn't *periodic* also used for magazines that come out every week or month? Therefore I would use *periodic*.

Comment: @md2perpe: "Periodical", yes.

Comment: Definition 1 of what?

Comment: @Clare the page that is linked immediately before the brackets, i.e. the Oxford dictionary definition of periodic.

Answer (score 24):

It's a *regular* service.

> **regular** *adjective*
>   2 Recurring at uniform intervals.
>   ‘a regular monthly check’
>   [- ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/regular)

Comment: To me, while this does indicate the type of service that is performed at regular intervals, it does not by-itself unambiguously indicate the recurring nature of an appointment.  If someone says "we'll schedule your regular service for the 12th" I would not be 100% clear whether subsequent appointments would automatically fall on the 12th.  At least, it would be more likely to interpret that if they said "we'll schedule recurring service on the 12th"

Comment: @DarrenRinger also, that could also be interpreted as "usual"

Comment: @DarrenRinger You bring up two points: recurrence and fixed dates. On *recurrence*, I disagree. While there may be ambiguity of definition (small / *regular* / large vs *regular* / irregular), once we're talking about "regular intervals" we're talking about something that recurs - otherwise, it would be a 'one-off' or 'ad hoc' service, not a 'regular' service. *Fixed dates each month*, however, does come within the semantic range of "regular intervals", as does *last day of each month* (which *isn't* the same number each month) - *that* ambiguity exists, but it isn't one the OP asked about.

Comment: @Lawrence I'd have to disagree with the answer here. The asker has given context where he has included this sentence: "A customer can book a one-time service or choose an interval.". In your case he'd have to write something like "A customer can book a one-time service or choose a regular service/interval" which seems ambiguous. Remember that it's not just you who needs to understand this sentence unambiguously. Recurring just fits this sentence the best. (Also, a regular interval service would not indicate a recurring one. A recurring service is automatically billed.)

Comment: "Regular" Is often misused to mean "frequent". For example, UK law requires children to attend school regularly, but the courts would not be amused if you claimed than one day per year on the same day every year was regular, even though it plainly is.

Answer (score 18):

As others have mentioned, the usual expression is *Recurring* service

> **recurring**
>   adjective UK ​ /rɪˈkɜː.rɪŋ/ US ​ /rɪˈkɝː.ɪŋ/
>   happening many times, or happening again

http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/recurring

Answer (score 10):

A "Subscription" is what I would go with. Especially if it's a service you are paying for, i.e... *subscribing* to.

Answer (score 1):

In gardening, when you sow a crop at regular intervals (e.g. I sow lettuce every 2 weeks) it is called *successive* sowing.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing wrong with using *weekly*, *monthly*, *daily* or using *once a* [week/month/day].

For example using:

> - To get booked into a *daily* service.
> - We provide *daily* services.
> - Services provided *daily*.

Or:

> - To get booked into a service *once a* week.
> - We provide services *once a* week.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. The question is: "What's the **generic word** for weekly/monthly etc. service?"

Comment: @AndyT - Neither are any of the other answers. They're all just adjectives that modify the word *service*. Therefore, "There's nothing wrong with using..." *is* the answer

Comment: @Mazura - I disagree with your "Neither are any of the other answers": "Regular", "Periodic" or "Recurring" are all words that generically cover the "weekly/monthly" part.

Answer (score -1):

**cyclical** as in :

> [cyclical events happen again and again in the same order or at the
>   same times](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/cyclical)

Comment: Hello, Maclek. It's good to add supporting evidence, but it's essential to attribute and link so as to avoid breach of copyright.

Comment: And to avoid [gaining unearned reputation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/160077/users-are-calling-me-a-plagiarist-what-do-i-do).

Answer (score -3):

I think you should pay attention to your context more than anything else.  Luckily for you, there is Amazon.com, to copy.  They use "Subscribe and save" for recurring orders.  I think it is simple and effective.

[image: Amazon's terminology for recurring.]