# What is the correct word/term/phrase for "publishing rate"?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice, word-usage, publishing

If a magazine is published weekly, what is that called? Its "publishing rate" is one week? Its "rate of publishing" is one week? It all sounds wrong.

Comment: It's *how often* the publication is publicated, or, perhaps you'd rather call it its *frequency*.

Comment: I'm glad this doesn't ask what bimonthly means

Answer (score 5):

The term most appropriate for the concept, in my experience, is **publishing frequency** or just **frequency**. This is supported by the [WikiProject Magazines Infobox template](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template:Infobox_magazine), which uses the term "frequency" to describe how often a magazine is published. It is also used more generally by blogs or any other outlet that produces written media on a certain schedule.

The term "publishing rate", while it certainly doesn't sound particularly bad and is occasionally used to refer to the publishing frequency of magazines or other written media, is typically more associated with scientific fields (see [Analysis of the publishing rate [...] of general surgery dissertations](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5506762/)) and hence, seems a little formal for describing something like a magazine.

In the context in which your audience are aware of the fact you're discussing a magazine (i.e, you're not talking about the concept but rather how it relates to a certain magazine), however, the preferable choice is likely to just use a term like "daily", "weekly", "monthly", or "yearly" (all of which refer to the [periodicity](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/326830/371769) of a publication) - this is easily understood and less formal.

An example of the term publishing rate used in context is [this article](https://www.bizjournals.com/bizwomen/news/latest-news/2017/10/time-inc-cuts-magazines-publishing-frequency.html), which uses the phrase as follows:

> Time Inc. cuts magazines' **publishing frequency**

On the other hand, an example of the terms used to refer to periodicity mentioned previously are the Wikipedia categories for magazines, which follow the format:

> Category: [Weekly/Monthly] magazines

(see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Weekly_magazines) and [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Monthly_magazines))