# What's the 'name' for the variation of period units that end in 'ly'?

Tags: measuring-units

If I call week, month, year, day = singular unit

weeks, months, years, days = plural unit

What do/can I call = weekly, monthly, yearly (though maybe 'annually'), daily - ?

PS: I'm aware of this similar question - [What is the collective term for "Daily", "Weekly", "Monthly" and "Yearly"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/326819/what-is-the-collective-term-for-daily-weekly-monthly-and-yearly) - but the ask-er seems to be after something slightly different, judging by the fact they accepted an answer that I'm not looking for. The answer, and other answers, provide generic words like "frequency" which can be used to describe all of the variations of the unit. In fact, the table in my application's database is called "frequencies" and I'm filling it with columns "singular", "plural" etc.

Comment: Lots of people use the term [***adverb of frequency***.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=%28is+an+adverb+of+frequency%29%2B%28are+adverbs+of+frequency%29&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2C%28is%20an%20adverb%20of%20frequency%29%20%2B%20%28are%20adverbs%20of%20frequency%29%3B%2Cc0)

Answer (score 1):

Daily, weekly, monthly, yearly (annually) are *periodic units*.

**periodic** adjective

**1 a** : occurring or recurring at regular intervals

[Merriam-Webster: periodic](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/periodic)

Comment: Ok thanks. 'Periodic' still seems to me too generic to distinguish between "week" and "weekly" but you have a good number of points and I only got a C in English in School. I won't mark your answer accepted just yet, will see what other's come up with and will have a read of that link you posted.

Comment: The term I’d use is frequency. That’s how often a periodic event occurs. The board meets periodically, usually semi-annually, for example.  So I’d call the column in your database frequency, not frequencies.

Comment: The two-word term _periodic units_ actually exists and is used (differently) in crystallography. Dan shows sense in being suspicious of your implication that this usage is anywhere near standard. An unhelpful answer on a site aimed at proficiency in English. Though 'weekly' etc can be adjectives, as adverbs they're termed 'frequency adverbs' as FF says.

Answer (score 0):

They are **adjectives** formed from those nouns denoting periods. There's no other specific word.

Comment: They're also adverbs.